# What is the most efficient way of sending data for a very large playlist over http?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json, http

I'm currently working on developing a web-based music player. The issue that I'm having is pulling a list of all the songs from the database and sending it to the client. The client has the ability to dynamically create playlists, and therefore they must have access to a list of the entire library. This library can range upwards of 20,000 unique songs. I'm preparing the data on the server-side using django and this tentative scheme:

```
{
  id: "1",
  cover: "http://example.com/AlbumArt.jpg",
  name: "Track Name",
  time: "3:15",
  album: "Album Name",
  disc: (1, 2),
  year: "1969",
  mp3: "http://example.com/Mp3Stream.mp3"
},

{
  id: "2",
  ...
}
```

What is the best method of DYNAMICALLY sending this information to the client? Should I be using jSON? Could jSON effectively send this text file consisting of 20,000 entries? Is it possible to cache this playlist on the client side so this huge request doesn't have to happen every time the user logs-in, instead only when there was a change in database?

Basically, what I need at this point is a dependable method of transmitting a text-based playlist consisting of around 20,000 objects, each with their own attributes (name, size, etc...), in a timely manor. Sort of like Google Music. When you log-in, you are presented with all the songs in your library. How are they sending this list?

Another minor question that comes to mind is, can the browser (mainly Chrome) handle this amount of data without sacrificing usability?

Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Why don't you use some sort of infinite scrolling or pagination? Does the user absolutely need to see all 20,000 at once?

Comment: I would suggest to use local storage. You can google about html5 local storage and use it.

Comment: This is what I've been told. The design I'm going for would be similar to that of Itunes/MusicBee/FooBar where you can view your library listing. The issue that I thought of with infinite scrolling is that when a user is looking to add new songs from library to a user-created playlist, the user would have specific songs in mind and would have to resort to multiple scroll -> wait for new data -> scroll more -> wait for new data... If they had a complete listing I think it would be more user friendly. @Blender

Comment: You can still use the theory behind the infinite scroll, just keep on refreshing until the complete list is on the device and then just update when necessary. I would for sure drop the _http://example.com/_ and have a base URL to save 40 or so bytes per entry - maybe only the track title, an ID and perhaps a cached thumbnail is needed - you now have 200 bytes = 4MB in a full list - without the http and stuff and minified it is 2.5MB

Comment: @DonJuma: Webapps and desktop apps aren't comparable here. Desktop apps can easily read and write 20mb databases of songs within a fraction of a second and still get away with it, as it's stored locally. Webapps have to be fairly light. I'd display only 500 or 1,000 at once and use infinite scrolling. Letting the user filter the songs will probably be a more important feature than displaying them all at once, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this http://code.flickr.net/2009/03/18/building-fast-client-side-searches/ ?

I've been using this array system myself lately (for 35K objects) and it is fast (assuming you dont want to render them all on screen).

Basically the server builds a long string in the form

1|2|3$cat|dog|horse$red|blue|green

Which is sent as a single string to an http request. Take the responseText field and conver it to an array using

```
Var arr = request.responseText.split('$');
Var ids = arr[0].split('|');
Var names = arr[1].split('|');
```

Clearly, you end up with arrays of strings at the end, not objects, but arrays are fast for many operations.  I've used $ and | as delimiters in this example, but for live use I use something more obscure. My 35k objects are completly handled in less than 0.5sec (iPad client).

You can save the strings to localstorage, but watch the 5Mb limit, or use a shim such as lawnchair. (nb I also like SpenserJ answer, which may be easier to implement depending on your environment)

This method doesn't easily work for all JSON datatypes, they need to be quite flat. I've also found these big arrays to behave well for performance, even on smartphones, ipod touch etc ( see jsperf.com for several tests around string.split and array searching)

Answer (score 2):

I just took a look at the network traffic for Google Play, and they will transmit the initial library screen (around 50 tracks) via JSON, with the bare minimum for metadata (name, track ID, and album art ID). When you load the main library page, it makes a request to an extremely basic HTML page, that appears to insert items from an inline JS object [Gist Sample](https://gist.github.com/SpenserJ/5835929). The total file was around 6MB, but it was cached and nothing needed to be transferred.

I would suggest doing a paginated JSON request to pull down the data, and using ETags and caching to ensure it isn't retransmitted unless it absolutely needs to be. And instead of a normal pagination of `?page=5&count=1000`, try `?from=1&to=1000`, so that deleting 995 will purge `?from=1&to=1000` from the cache, but not `?from=1001&to=2000` (whereas `?page=2&count=1000` would).

Google Play Music does *not* appear to use Local Storage, IndexedDB, or Web SQL, and loads everything from the cached file and parses it into a JS object.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a file-like object that wraps the json file and spits out proper chunks.

For instance, you know that your json file is a single array of music objects, you could create a generator that wraps the json file and returns chunks of the array.

You would have to do some string content parsing to get the chunking of the json file right.

I don't know what generates your json content. If possible, I would consider generating a number of managable files, instead of one huge file.

Answer (score 0):

I would test performance of sending the complete JSON in a single request. Chances are that the slowest part will be rendering the UI and not the response time of the JSON request. I recommend storing the JSON in a JavaScript object on the page, and only render UI dynamically as needed based on scrolling. The JavaScript object can serve as a data source for the client side scrolling. Should the JSON be too large, you may want to consider server backed scrolling.

This solution will also be browser agnostic (HTML < 5 )