# Alternative to creating large client side Javascript array of objects via JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, object, optimization, graph

I have a website that contains graphs which display employee activity records. There are tiers of data (ie: region -> state -> office -> manager -> employee -> activity record) and each time you click the graph it drills down a level to get to display more specific information. The highest level (region) requires me to load  ~1000 objects into an array and the lowest level is ~500,000 objects. I am populating the graphs via a JSON formatted text file using:

```
$.ajax({url:'data/jsondata.txt', dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        largeArray = data.employeeRecords;
}
```

Is there an alternative method I could use without hindering response time/performance? I am caught up in the thought that I must pre-load all of the data client side otherwise there will be lagtime if I need to fetch it on a user click. If anyone can point me to best practices and maybe even explain what is considered "TOO MUCH" client side data i'd appreciate it.

FYI i'm restricted to using an old web server and if I want to do anything server side i'd be limited to classic ASP otherwise it has to be client side. thank you!

Comment: What does an individual record look like/contain? One field, lots of fields, nested arrays ? Datatypes?

Comment: name, region, office, manager, employee number, activitytype, startTimestamp, endTimestamp.  That is an example of a record - nothing nested within it. managers asking for detail at that level PER person (several hundred activies per day, several hundred employees)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If your server responds quickly**

In this case, you can probably simply load data on demand when a user clicks. The server is quick, so why bother trying to be smarter for no gain.

If the server is quick, but not quick enough, then you might be able to preload the next level while drawing the first. Eg if you have just rendered the graph at the "office" level, then silently preload the "manager" next level down data while the user is still reacting to the screen update.

**If the server is too slow for data on demand**

In this case you probably need to model exactly where it is slow and address that. There are several things in play here and your question doesnt exactly say.

1. Is the server slow to query the database, if yes fix it. There is little you can do client side to solve this.
2. Is the server slow to package for transmission? Harder to fix, server big enough?
3. Network transmission is slow? Hmmm, need to send less data or get users onto faster bandwidth.
4. Browser unpack time is slow? (ie delay decoding the data before your script can chart it). Change how you package the data, or send less data, such as chunks.

Can browsers handle 500,000 objects?  You should be able to just monitor memory of tHe browser you are using, and there are opionions yes/no on this. Will really depend or target users browser/hardware.

You might like to look at this question [What is the most efficient way of sending data for a very large playlist over http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247392/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-sending-data-for-a-very-large-playlist-over-ht/17251006#17251006) as it shows an alternative way of sending and handling data which I've found to be much quicker for step 4 above. Of course, at 500k objects you will no longer be able to use localStorage, but I've been experimenting with downloading millions of array elements and it works ok. ( still WIP ) I dont use jquery, so not sure how useable this is either.

Best practice? Sorry cannot help with that part of the question.